# Batch file IF file exists GOTO

Tags: windows, batch-file

i'm trying to write a simple if exists in batch but getting an error.

> GOTO was unexpected at this time.

Below is my code:

```
::find /i "The OU has been created" error_ou.log

IF errorlevel 0 (echo Success. The OU has been created) GOTO :success

IF errorlevel 1 (echo Fail. The OU has NOT been created) GOTO :fail

    :success

    :fail
```

the error_ou.log file is generated before this part of the script from another command, it's always generated and always has the text time im doing a /find for. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simple edit:

```
find /i "The OU has been created" error_ou.log

IF errorlevel 1 (echo Fail. The OU has NOT been created & GOTO :fail)

IF errorlevel 0 (echo Success. The OU has been created & GOTO :success)

:success

:fail
```

Comment: you are very welcome, and i hope you continue to bring your programing problems here if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

```
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo failure
    goto failure
) else (
    echo success
    goto success
)
```

Or, more similar to your code

```
if errorlevel 1 ( echo failure & goto failure )
echo success & goto success
```

There are two problems with your code.

The fist is causing the error you see: you forget to include the `else` keyword and/or the concatenation of the two commands in the `if`.

The second is a logic error. `if errorlevel n` will be true for any errorlevel value equal or greater than `n`, so if your first test is `if errorlevel 0`, it will "always" be true. Check for errorlevel must be done from higher to lower values.

That way, in the second sample code, the `if errorlevel 0` is omited, the previous `if errorlevel 1` will handle any error from the `find` command, leaving only the case of `errorlevel 0`.

Comment: they are two seperate ifs, its completely legal to not have an else if one is not wanted.

Comment: @nephi12, yes, bad explained, i was editing it while you comment. Thank you

Comment: but what if the OP later wants to add a third check? it just isnt a good model... it works yes, but it isnt good style, rather you should preform the check, at *least* use `else if`

Comment: of course they do, but saying that is about as useful as saying the sky is blue, everyone knows it, and it has nothing to do with this, as the OP is using `if`. if you wanna talk about something besides if, go chat with someone.

Answer (score -2):

Wrong syntax. Use:
IF something GOTO somewhere

But you can't use:
IF something Do something and then GOTO somewhere

Try:

```
IF errorlevel 0 GOTO success
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO fail

:success
Echo Success:  The OU has been created
GOTO end

:fail
Echo Fail
GOTO end

:end
```

Comment: if "string" EQU "%var%" (echo they are equal & goto next)

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` is **always** true so it will always go to `success`.